# How is "domino release" updated in the "all server documents" view?

Tags: ibm-domino, documents

Recently upgraded Domino servers from 6.5.3fp to 8.5.1, the "domino release" in the All Documents view has never updated for one of the servers and it been rebooted several times and going on over a month.   Why is the "domino release" not showing the correct version?

Answer (score 1):

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21095942